# If I want to download a Google sheet to CSV locally, do I need "redirect_uris" defined for Google API v4?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-sheets, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use the Python API with Google API v4 to locally download a Google sheet and convert it to a CSV file.  I'm happy for this to run as a script on my local machine.  I don't need web abilities.  I have this Python code ...

```
from gsheets import Sheets
...
        sheets = Sheets.from_files('/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/configuration_g_client.json')
        url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifpqxxxxxxxxxxxxx5gmvevJ7jc-xxxxxxxxjDS8Me7U/edit#gid=0'
        s = sheets.get(url)
        out = s.sheets[3].to_csv('Spam.csv', encoding='utf-8', dialect='excel')
        print(out)
```

The configuration_g_client.json file that was downloaded from Google looks like the below ...

```
{"web":
    {
        "client_id":"124xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id":"ccc-directory-xxxxxxxxx08","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"xxxxxx13s9",
        "javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8000"]
    }
}
```

But this line

sheets = Sheets.from_files('/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/configuration_g_client.json')

dies with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gsheets/api.py", line 31, in from_files
    creds = oauth2.get_credentials(scopes, secrets, storage, no_webserver)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gsheets/oauth2.py", line 48, in get_credentials
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(secrets, scopes)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2134, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename,
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 126, in _loadfile
    return _validate_clientsecrets(obj)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 99, in _validate_clientsecrets
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError(
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web".
```

If I want to run locally, should I be using a different client type?  Otherwise, what value do I need to set for "redirect_uris"?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I updated my credentials JSON file to include

```
"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8000"]
```

and now when I run my script locally, it attempts to spawn a browser

[image]

This is bad becauase I want to run the script locally through a cron job and don't want to have to interact with a browser.

**Edit:** Per the suggestion given about running the script using a service account.  I created the service account following teh instructions here -- https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/authentication#service .  Below are the resulting project and key screens ...

[image]
[image]

The credentials JSON file looks like this

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "chicommons",
  "private_key_id": "ecf14d...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCcSISusTKvBcO1\nRn9bdD/vYWYyoi0ERi5P0u8+iJQ6WUmYIkKG2aYfyp3kt1/KQJ4YW0M4/AUGAQlz\n5FdS1kTqHkmzwtd+FN8FE6...xxx.../OmXZkvjQej2eA6Txcm/hfuyebkrXnyUm\nycuVzNRsywvGQf/7gWP0y9oQ\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "google-sheets-download@chicommons.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "116134130252723375625",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/google-sheets-download%40chicommons.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

but now when I run my script to attempt to download my Google sheet, I get this error

```
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, how about the following modification?

From your `configuration_g_client.json`, I noticed `"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8000"]` and no `redirect_uris`. So please add `http://localhost:8080/` to `redirect_uris` and test it again. The following image is for setting `http://localhost:8080/` to `redirect_uris`. In this case, you can remove `javascript_origins` as follows.

[image]

- Here, please set `http://localhost:8080/` as the value of `redirect_uris` and click "SAVE" button. The last character of `http://localhost:8080/` is `/`. It seems that the default `redirect_uris` is `http://localhost:8080/` for `oauth2.get_credentials`. Please be careful.

### Answer for updated question:

- In your updated question, you want to download a CSV data from Google Drive using the service account instead of OAuth2 with python.

For this, I think that your script for authorizing is required to be modified. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for achieving your goal using the service account.

#### IMPORTANT:

When the service account is used, there is an important point. It's that the Google Drive of the service account is different from your Google Drive. So in order to download the Google Spreadsheet in your Google Drive, please share the Google Spreadsheet with the email of the service account. By this, the file can be downloaded by the service account. Please be careful this. You can see it as `client_email` in the credential file of service account.

#### Sample script 1:

Before you use this, please set the variables of `credentialFileOfServiceAccount`, `emailOfServiceAccount` and `file_id`.

```
import requests
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentialFileOfServiceAccount = './###.json'
emailOfServiceAccount = '###'
file_id = '###'

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentialFileOfServiceAccount, scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly')
access_token = creds.create_delegated(emailOfServiceAccount).get_access_token().access_token

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file_id + '/export?mimeType=text%2Fcsv'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.text)

with open('Spam.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

- When above script is run, the Spreadsheet of `file_id` is exported as the CSV data, and the data is saved as a file of `Spam.csv`. In this case, the data of 1st tab of Spreadsheet is retrieved. This is the same with your script.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, googleapis for python is used.

```
import io
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

credentialFileOfServiceAccount = './###.json'
file_id = '###'

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentialFileOfServiceAccount, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
request = service .files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/csv')
fh = io.FileIO('Spam.csv', mode='wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

### Answer for one last follow-up question:

At above sample scripts, the 1st tab is exported as the CSV data. In order to export the sheets except for the 1st tab the Google Spreadsheet, in this answer, I would like to propose to change the endpoint. I thought that this way might be simpler. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this, please set the variables of `credentialFileOfServiceAccount`, `emailOfServiceAccount` and `file_id`. And also, please set the sheet name you want to export.

```
import requests
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentialFileOfServiceAccount = './###.json'
emailOfServiceAccount = '###'
file_id = '###'
sheet_name = 'Sheet2' # <--- Please set the sheet name you want to export.

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentialFileOfServiceAccount, scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly')
access_token = creds.create_delegated(emailOfServiceAccount).get_access_token().access_token

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + file_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=' + sheet_name
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.text)

with open('Spam.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

- If you want to use the sheet ID (gid), the endpoint is as follows.

  ```
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + file_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + gid
  ```
- When above script is run, "Sheet2" in the Spreadsheet of `file_id` is exported as the CSV data, and the data is saved as a file of `Spam.csv`.

Comment: I edited my question with some more info.  I ultimately want to run this through a cron job and don't want to have to interact with a browser.  What do I need to do to get my credentials into a place where I can just run the script and download the CSV without having to do any browser interactions while running it?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying. I noticed that you had updated your question now. I apologize for this. About your updated question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. from your updated question, I noticed that my answer was not used. My suggested modification point is that `redirect_uris` is set as `http://localhost:8080/`. But in your updated question, it's `http://localhost:8000`. At first, in order to resolve your initial question, can you modify it and test it again.

Comment: @Dave About your new question of `download the CSV without having to do any browser interactions while running it?`, how about using the service account? When the service account is used, the access token can be retrieved without opening the browser.

Comment: Hi, Not to quibble, but this is not a new question -- my goal is the same.  I want to download a Google sheet into CSV using a script.  I edited my question to include the steps and error I received when I tried the service account route you suggested.  Man, why does Google make this so hard?

Comment: @Dave I noticed that I forgot to reply to your comment now. I apologize for this. I added the sample scripts for exporting the Spreadsheet as CSV file. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks -- a quick clarification, I want to download the Google sheet as a CSV to my local machine, not to a Google drive account.  Given that, where in the sample scripts you provided do I put the URL to my Google sheet?  (it has the format https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifpqssssssssss5gmvevJ7jc-cFzzzzzzzMe7U/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying. If you want to download the Spreadsheet of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifpqssssssssss5gmvevJ7jc-cFzzzzzzzMe7U/edit#gid=0` as the CSV file to the local PC, please use the Spreadsheet ID. In your sample URL, the Spreadsheet ID is `1ifpqssssssssss5gmvevJ7jc-cFzzzzzzzMe7U`. In above 2 sample scripts of "Sample script 1" and "Sample script 2", please use it like `file_id = '1ifpqssssssssss5gmvevJ7jc-cFzzzzzzzMe7U'`. By this, when the Spreadsheet can be accessed by the service account, a CSV file is created to the local PC.

Comment: Awesome!  It looks like it is working, but i do have one last follow-up.  The Google sheet I have has several sheets (tabs).  The code above seems to download the first one but I would like to get a different one (the third sheet).  How can I specify which sheet in the Google sheet I'm interested in?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `one last follow-up`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.